# how can I add a html script inside my android app?

Tags: android

how can I add a html script inside my android app?

I have google admob inside my android app now, I would like to change the google admob ads with my own ads, my ads fromat is :

"< script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx">"

how  can i do that? thx

Comment: "_how can I add a html script_" Please tell me, what exactly is an HTML script?

Comment: If you want to replace google adds with your adds then please use webview for this

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.xxxxcomxx"></script>

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

use webview and
you can try this:

```
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored<b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: thanks so much !!  but I don't know how can I change the google ads with this webview code..can give me more details ?? thx^^

Comment: webview is a provide you to facility of writing HTML code...you can learn about webview on upper link and use it may be this will help you.